# Is an apostraphy allowed to appear unencoded in the content occurring between start and end XML tags?

Tags: .net, xml, rss

In an attempt to write an RSS reader I ran into problems with the .NET XML Reader throwing an exception if an unencoded apostraphy appeared between the start and end tags found in an RSS feed.

I am wonderring, is the XMLReader in .NET 2.0 not completely standards compliant? Or did I run into someone's buggy implementation of a feed generator?

For clarification, I was working on RSS version 2.0, that was also the version number I found in the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the W3C markup validator, an unencoded apostraphy (') is allowed to appear within the content between start and end tags in XML.

It appears that the problem I reported as having occurred in my question was caused by a bug in an old version of the Microsoft XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the feed passes the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).  That should give you a quick answer to who is outside the rules.

Comment: That's good advice. That's exactly what I did when an RSS feed that I needed to read from contained duplicate identifiers. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  While it did not answer the title question directly, I now have enough information to post a correct answer, according to the result of my validation test which had to be done with a handwritten XML file as I no longer have the original.  I reproduced the condition I described, and it was detected as being well formed XML.

I upgraded IE from 6 to 7 since having the problem, and now the XML with an unencoded apostraphy shows up without error in IE, I just need to do the test for RSS in .NET.